# Optional attributes in a define in puppet

Tags: puppet

What's the proper way to define optional attributes in a define in puppet? Right now I'm doing this:

```
define($command = "none") {
}
```

and then things like (in a template):

```
<% if command != "none" %>
do something with <%= command %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a more proper way to define optional attributes? Something more akin to nil or null instead of "none"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [undef](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_datatypes.html#undef). In the define you use it explicitly, like:

```
define($command = undef) {
}
```

while in templates, undef variables won't get instance variables define, so they'll be nil:

```
<% if @command %>
do something with <%= @command %>
<% end %>
```